# npx create-react-app returns "Maximum call stack size exceeded"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app, npx

I keep getting Maximum call stack size exceeded after npx: install X in Ys.

Tried clearing cache, uninstalling and reinstalling.

How do I solve this? I'm just trying to run create-react-app

Additional info:

```js
C:\Users\Aros\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\node_modules\fs-extra\lib\mkdirs\mkdirs-sync.js:24
  mode = o777 & (~process.umask())
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
  at mkdirsSync (C:\Users\Aros\AppData\Local\Yarn\Data\global\node_modules\fs-extra\lib\mkdirs\mkdirs-sync.js:24:21)
  at mkdirsSync (C:\Users\Aros\AppData\Local\Yarn\Data\global\node_modules\fs-extra\lib\mkdirs\mkdirs-sync.js:36:14)
  at mkdirsSync (C:\Users\Aros\AppData\Local\Yarn\Data\global\node_modules\fs-extra\lib\mkdirs\mkdirs-sync.js:37:7)
  at mkdirsSync (C:\Users\Aros\AppData\Local\Yarn\Data\global\node_modules\fs-extra\lib\mkdirs\mkdirs-sync.js:37:7)
  at mkdirsSync (C:\Users\Aros\AppData\Local\Yarn\Data\global\node_modules\fs-extra\lib\mkdirs\mkdirs-sync.js:37:7)
  at mkdirsSync (C:\Users\Aros\AppData\Local\Yarn\Data\global\node_modules\fs-extra\lib\mkdirs\mkdirs-sync.js:37:7)
  at mkdirsSync (C:\Users\Aros\AppData\Local\Yarn\Data\global\node_modules\fs-extra\lib\mkdirs\mkdirs-sync.js:37:7)
  at mkdirsSync (C:\Users\Aros\AppData\Local\Yarn\Data\global\node_modules\fs-extra\lib\mkdirs\mkdirs-sync.js:37:7)
  at mkdirsSync (C:\Users\Aros\AppData\Local\Yarn\Data\global\node_modules\fs-extra\lib\mkdirs\mkdirs-sync.js:37:7)
  at mkdirsSync (C:\Users\Aros\AppData\Local\Yarn\Data\global\node_modules\fs-extra\lib\mkdirs\mkdirs-sync.js:37:7)
```

Node version: v12.17.0

OS: Windows 10 Pro

Not working with yarn or node. Both latest versions. Tried with create-react-app installed and uninstalled (so straight through npx)

Comment: This [post](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/5328#issuecomment-429148117) may be helpful.

Comment: @SMAKSS don't even have that file to delete sadly.

Comment: I think [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56717221/maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded-while-installing-create-react-app-on-linux) may help you

Comment: @reymon359 I'm on my C drive already though.